# Command to enable/disable USB portable drive on the fly without rebooting Win2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, usb, drive

Is there any command or 3rd-party tool to enable/disable USB portable drive on the fly without rebooting the Win2003 Server that it is plugged into?

This is for enabling the drive before a backup job starts, and for disabling it after backup completes for security reasons. All these should be done via scripting or cmd.exe batch file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Requires some logging in/out, but might suit your needs:

http://diaryproducts.net/about/operating_systems/windows/disable_usb_sticks

Answer (score 1):

THis will help on remounting: [Re-mount USB device after removal on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/44339/re-mount-usb-device-after-removal-on-windows/46597): [SafelyRemove](http://safelyremove.com/) app has a nice console backend.