# How to remount unmounted USB drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, mount, usb, usb-flash-drive, automount

How to remount USB drive in Windows after it was unmounted, without unplugging and replugging again?

Comment: This question would probably suit SuperUser more, but to answer your question, I believe you can re-mount drives through Control Panel --> Add hardware wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found existing questions:

- [Re-mount USB device after removal on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/44339/re-mount-usb-device-after-removal-on-windows)
- https://superuser.com/questions/32023/how-do-i-get-windows-vista-or-windows-7-to-re-attach-a-usb-device-without-having